# Eclipse - Push local PHP changes from dev machine to remote location via SFTP

Tags: php, eclipse, sftp, web-deployment

We have multiple dev machines and a Git server on the same network, and a Web server (on a different network that we talk to via SFTP).

All dev machines sync code using Git. Occasionally, we want to do a one-way push from any of dev machines to the Web Server via SFTP.

I've been exploring the built-in RSE and Team Synchronizing feature within Eclipse to move changes from Dev machines to the Web Server, but it seems to be a two-way syncing mechanism. Often it tries to overwrite the local files by pulling (doing a GET) from the Web Server, and refuses to show the PUT option.

Is there any other way to do a deliberate file push?